# Find Width of Excel Scroll Bar

Tags: excel, scrollbar, active-window, vba

Activewindow.UsableWidth gives me the width of the screen with the Vertical Scroll Bar's width included. Is there a way I can calculate the width of the Scroll Bar? I measured it by having one shape be UsableWidth and the other shape be what I actually can see, and the difference is the width of the Scroll Bar. I'm wondering if there's a way to automate it so it can be used by a user with a higher or lower resolution, and therefore smaller or larger Scroll Bar.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to find the value for the vertical scrollbar width, you can use a Windows API call:

```
Declare Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "user32" Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Public Const SM_CXVSCROLL = 2

______________________________________

Sub ShowVScrollWidth()

    Dim lVScrollWidth As Long

    lVScrollWidth = GetSystemMetrics32(SM_CXVSCROLL)

    Debug.Print lVScrollWidth

End Sub
```

(Adapted from the info on [this page](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/determining_the_users_video_resolution/). More info on the available GetSystemMetrics parameters can be found at [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx).)

Comment: This covers 99.95% of the screen, which is as close as someone can get I assume. Thank you so much for the quick response!